# WooCommerce List Top Selling Products & Categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to write PHP code to list top selling items (with quantity) and top selling categories (with total sales amount) in a tabular form in descending order.

Item | Quantity

Category | Sales

I know we can retrieve this from Reports screen in WooCommerce, but I need to get this values so I can display them else where in the WordPress admin panel in a widget. I know how to create dashboard widgets, by the way.

Does anyone know how to implement this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Here you will find the answer on how to get the top selling product categories: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66831414/10447197

Answer (score 2):

you should look into woocommerce files and look for `WC_Admin_Report`. You can see some examples and work your way with what you want.

I'll give you this example I made.

```
add_action('init', 'reports');

function reports() {


    include_once(WC()->plugin_path().'/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-admin-report.php');
    $wc_report = new WC_Admin_Report();

    $data = $wc_report->get_order_report_data( array(
        'data' => array(
            '_qty' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => 'SUM',
                'name' => 'quantity'
            ),
            '_line_subtotal' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => 'SUM',
                'name' => 'gross'
            ),
            '_product_id' => array(
                'type' => 'order_item_meta',
                'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
                'function' => '',
                'name' => 'product_id'
            ),
            'order_item_name' => array(
                'type'     => 'order_item',
                'function' => '',
                'name'     => 'order_item_name',
            ),
        ),

        'group_by'     => 'product_id',

        'order_by'     => 'quantity DESC',

        'query_type' => 'get_results',

        'limit' => 20,

        'order_status' => array( 'completed', 'processing' ),
    ) );

    print_r($data);

}
```

sample output of `print_r($data);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 4
            [gross] => 140
            [product_id] => 53
            [order_item_name] => Happy Ninja
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 3
            [gross] => 36
            [product_id] => 70
            [order_item_name] => Flying Ninja
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [gross] => 10
            [product_id] => 50
            [order_item_name] => Patient Ninja
        )

)
```

you have the data and that would get you up and running for `Item | Quantity`.