# How to get best selling product category IDs in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I looking for way to display the 6 best selling product categories.
this is what i got now:

```
$termsprent = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'    => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty'  => true,
        'numberposts' => 4,
        'meta_key'    => 'total_sales',
        'orderby'     => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'       => 'desc',
    )
);
```

does anyone knows a way to modify it so it will display the top selling product categories?

Answer (score 5):

**GETS THE TOTAL SUM OF SALES OF A PRODUCT CATEGORY**

You can use the following function **to get the total sum of sales of products** belonging to a specific product category.

> The only parameter of the function is the **product category ID**
> *(term_id)*

```
// gets the total sales count of a specific product category
function counts_total_sales_by_product_category( $term_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $total_sales = $wpdb->get_var("
        SELECT sum(meta_value)
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON ( {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id )
        WHERE ( {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id IN ($term_id) )
        AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'total_sales'"
    );
    return $total_sales;
}
```

**GET THE BEST SELLING PRODUCT CATEGORIES**

The following function **will return an array with the best selling product categories** sorted in descending order.

> The only parameter of the function is **the limit of product categories
> to be returned**.

```
// gets the n product categories with the best sales
function gets_best_selling_product_categories( $limit ) {

    $total_sales = array();
    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_cat ) {
        $product_cat_id = $product_cat->term_id;
        $total_sales[$product_cat_id] = counts_total_sales_by_product_category( $product_cat_id );
    }

    // removes empty values from the array
    $total_sales = array_filter( $total_sales );

    // sorts the array values in descending order
    arsort( $total_sales );

    // gets the first n ($limit) product categories with the most sales
    $best_product_categories = array_slice( $total_sales, 0, $limit, true );

    return $best_product_categories;
}
```

**RESULT**

Below is the result of the `var_dump()` of the `gets_best_selling_product_categories( 4 );` function:

```
array(4) {
    [15]=> string(3) "209"
    [30]=> string(3) "160"
    [32]=> string(2) "56"
    [31]=> string(2) "18"
}
```

The array **key** will be the product category id and its **value** is the total sum of sales for that category.

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: If we change `gets_best_selling_product_categories` function signature to `$limit = null` we can use function witout limiting output

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified and extended version of [@vincenzo-di-gaetano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66831414/11977152) answer.

Function immediately returns the array of WP_Terms. As for me, it is more convenient, although the object is modified.
Result will be like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> object(WP_Term)#3977 (11) { 
    ["term_id"]=> int(15)
    ["name"]=> string(13) "Uncategorized"
    ...
    ["sales"]=> string(1) "5" 
  } 
  [1]=> object(WP_Term)#3978 (11) { 
    ["term_id"]=> int(16)
    ["name"]=> string(13) "Uncategorized 2"
    ...
    ["sales"]=> string(1) "3" 
  } 
}
```

```php
function popular_product_categories( $limit = null ): array {
    $terms = array();
    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_cat ) {
        // set total sales property
        $product_cat->sales = counts_total_sales_by_product_category( $product_cat->term_id );
        $terms[$product_cat->term_id] = $product_cat;
    }

    // filter out empty terms
    $terms = array_filter( $terms, fn($term) => $term->sales > 0 );

    // sort the terms by sales values in descending order
    usort($terms, fn($a, $b) => $a->sales <=> $b->sales);

    return array_slice( $terms, 0, $limit, true );
}
```

Caching is also appropriate for such operations, so I added it to the example:

```php
// Return total sales number for a product category
function counts_total_sales_by_product_category( $term_id, $use_cache = true ): ?string {
    global $wpdb;
    $cache = $use_cache ? get_transient( 'total_sales_term_'.$term_id ) : false;
    
    // Check if we can return value early
    if ( false !== $cache ) {
        return $cache;
    }
    $total_sales = $wpdb->get_var("
        SELECT sum(meta_value)
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON ( {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id )
        WHERE ( {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id IN ($term_id) )
        AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'total_sales'"
    );
    // Update cache value
    set_transient( 'total_sales_term_'.$term_id, $total_sales, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    return $total_sales;
}
```

Additionally, we can update cache when the order is completed

```php
// Update counts_total_sales_by_product_category transient when a product is sold
function update_total_sales_term_transient( $order_id ): void {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $product_categories = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
        if ( ! empty( $product_categories ) ) {
            // recalculate total sales for each category
            foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
                counts_total_sales_by_product_category( $product_category->term_id, false); // use the second parameter to override the cache
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'update_total_sales_term_transient');
```